# Error with boost::serialization::shared_ptr_helper

Tags: c++, boost

By including , I get the error:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr_helper.hpp:182:20: error: no matching function for
call to 'std::map<const void*, std::shared_ptr<void>, std::less<const void*>, std::allocator<std::
pair<const void* const, std::shared_ptr<void> > > >::insert(std::pair<const void*, std::
shared_ptr<const bagel::Atom> >)'
             result = m_o_sp->insert(std::make_pair(oid, s));
```

What's wrong?? The version of std and boost are both the newest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not get that "by including". I know this, because `bagel::Atom` is not a part of boost.

You simply cannot expect to store a `shared_ptr<const bagel::Atom> >` into a `std::shared_ptr<void>` without an explicit cast (`static_pointer_cast`?).

Using

```
std::map<void*, std::shared_ptr<void> >
```

is a huge design smell though. You can definitely not expect any of that to be automatically serialized anyway (because, how would `void` be usefully serialized?)

Comment: Sure, I do not, it is part of the project I am compiling. I see, thanks much.

Comment: I produced a similar error when updating from Boost 1.55 to 1.56 (though I'm still using the 2010 compiler so the error is different).  This offending code is clearly in the Boost header, so... how can one get around it?  I'm not about to fix the Boost code itself!

Comment: @aldo The "offending code" is a template instantiation. I can't see your particular code, but in the OP's case the point of instantiation is _in his code_ and the template instantiation arguments cause the problem. They are "clearly" not in the boost header. Repeat after me: "_garbage in -> garbage out_"  :). (A good mantra for header-only libraries in particular)

Comment: @aldo: It's more than possible that you produced garbage for 1.55 as well, and it just happened to work. Appearing to produce valid results is not a useful test for non-garbage.

Comment: @sehe My sincere apologies to you.  I must be having a bad day.  I've removed by comment and will re-phrase...

Comment: I recently encountered the same (or similar) problem when upgrading from Boost 1.55 to Boost 1.56 (with MSVC 2010) without changing anything else in my code.  I'm serializing a derived class that contains a `std::map<boost::shared_ptr<widget>, ...>` as a member.  This was working fine before, but now produces errors referring to `shared_ptr_helper`.  I'm investigating further and may post another question with details.

Comment: @aldo Mmm. Not too sure that sounds like the same thing, really. But yeah, if upgrading boost breaks your compilation, that sounds like an interesting case. I'm looking forward to a SSCCE :)

Comment: @sehe I found it: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10488.  I'll be trying to get the bug re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

Your breakage is probably the result of a change in the Boost Serialization library in v1.56.  I have experienced similar problems as a result.  After a day of searching, testing, pulling my hair out, etc. I found (actually my colleague found) this bug filed against Boost:

"Compilation of serializing shared_ptr<const Object> fails" (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10488)

The bad news is that the bug as been closed and the behavior deemed "an improvement."  I disagree and may try to get the bug re-opened.

---

UPDATE 5/24/15: The Boost bug has received more attention and was reportedly fixed "4 weeks ago."  No final word on which version contains the fix, but as of 1.58 it seemed NOT to be in yet.

Comment: That looks related. And I agree there's to much value in `shared_ptr <T const>` to dismiss it completely